# Visual Studio solution can't find System.Web.Http.WebHost

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

As the description says, all of a sudden the solution can't find `System.Web.Http.WebHost` for some reason.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved it by installing NuGet `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost`.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost
```

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost/